# Did AT&T do a lazy job with this wiring

Tags: wiring

AT&T came out today to install fiber. Instead of running it through the unfinished basement, they instead ran the wire up my exterior wall as shown in the photo. I'm not sure if this is normal but it looks terrible IMO. Am I overreacting? Is this the lazy way to install the fiber? [image: att wiring]

Comment: It's not just AT&T, they are often contractors that get paid by the job.  Whatever gets the job done fastest is what they do.

Comment: Depends if you asked them to put though the basement or just hook it up and let them be.

Comment: I have never seen a proper install for any of the well-known internet providers in the US. Whether it is cable, AT&T, or Verizon, it's always half-assed like this. Satellite tv installers are only marginally better, and that I think because if they screw it up too badly roofs leak and parabolics get torn off in windstorms ripping shingles with them.

Comment: Definitely not out of the ordinary, however your house is stucco which is an absolute pita to fasten into.

Comment: Wow, a surprise they would just drape it like that, since it is vulnerable to sharp bends.

Comment: When I built my house, I wouldn't let the phone company or cable company anywhere near my house.  They are total hacks.    Doing the site planning involved building a pump house where I had all the utilities terminated at (power, phone, cable) and  then I ran them  in buried conduit to a furnace/utility room in the house.   Keep those hacks (cable and telco) at a much of a distance as possible.

Comment: Installers do not want to spend the time (or take the liability) to figure out how to fish walls inside your house.
If you want that you'd be better off installing the drop before the provider shows up, then ask them to connect to it.

Comment: If you run your own stuff, and do a decent job, they'll be happy to do two connections - one from outside to your starting point and then one more for the telco-supplied equipment (router/etc.) at the other end. If not, they either put it all in the easiest location (e.g., just inside the basement) or they connect it to one spot in the house that you specify, **but using the easiest/cheapest way to get there**. I remember one many years ago where they went into the basement and ran coax up the edge of a staircase. I couldn't believe the customer let them do it, but they were OK with it.

Answer (score 3):

### Fairly bone stock standard.

Telephone *(et al)* companies have not willingly gone into residential basements in a long time. They want the absolute minimum responsibility for wiring in concealed spaces and the time it takes to run that. It's quicker and any subsequent damage is more obvious if the cable run is all on the exterior of the building. If you want concealed wiring via the basement, you get to run it yourself before they show up and have them connect to it at their exterior interface.

The fiber appears to be (unsurprisingly, that's exactly what it's made for) reinforced "drop" fiber which is in the same physical format as telephone drop cable, and has two reinforcing rods that limit its bending (the fiber inside it is also typically, but not always, "reduced bend radius" fiber that is not particularly sensitive to bending - can be wrapped around a pencil and work fine.) The arc away from the building penetration is characteristic of this type of reinforced cable. The reinforcement keeps the fiber(s) (running in a tube between them) from ever seeing a sharp bend.

Most likely the installer(s) [probably subcontractors, not AT&T employees] were paid a fixed fee to connect your house, and in that case, speed is directly proportional to rate of pay, and any additional time costs them (not AT&T) money. So they will do it precisely to whatever AT&T's minimum standard is.

Answer (score 1):

If the ISP ran that underground cable up to your house and terminated it on your outside wall, not in your basement, that is how it's done and I don't think it looks so terrible.

But the black wire running up the wall from the box looks terrible, and you are not overreacting.  That box is their termination point and any further wiring is your responsibility.  If you paid them to do that further wiring you should tell them to come back and do it nicely.  That doesn't mean they'll run it through walls, they might only be willing to do it the easiest possible way, but they should do a much nicer job.  Even *functionally* it's deficient.  There should be a drip loop to shed water that runs down that black cable.  There is a loop there, but the cable comes into contact with the top of the box and runs behind it first, so all the water will be shed there!

Comment: The box is raintight. If water is shed on top of it, it does not care, so long as the loop runs below before coming up into it. Yeah, I personally would like to see a couple more feet of cable so the run was vertical down the side of the house and then over to the box, but it's "functional" as is.